# Positioning of submit button on Android falling off bottom of screen on smaller displays

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm having a problem with the positioning of a submit button - it's being pushed off the bottom of the display on smaller phones, e.g. 800 x 480. Several less important fields fall off as well, but it's critical that the submit button be viewable and clickable.

I could solve this issue by moving the button to somewhere in the middle of the screen. I don't want to put it at the *top* of the screen, because that would look strange. By if I put in the middle, perhaps underneath an icon and its identifier, it might not look too bad? Underneath the button there would be a description and several other shorter categorization fields.  My basic question is, is it really bad form to show a submit button in the middle of a display?

Comment: Use a relative layout, then add your button to it and align it to the bottom of the parent.

Comment: I think in addition to that you need to put the content above in a ScrollView.  But I might be wrong - experiment!

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. It can't overlap the fields above it, right?

Comment: I see. Ok, I'll try it.